# How do I safely distribute a ninja component build?

Tags: g++, clang, clang++, ninja, gn

#### Context

I am compiling Chromium using [autoninja](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/+/refs/heads/main/autoninja.py) and the `is_component_build` build flag which quote *"links many parts of the build into separate shared libraries to avoid the long link step at the end.*

This is really helpful especially if you consider **running incremental builds**, which means that only the parts of the codebase that have changed are rebuilt.

#### The problem

Now, turning our attention to the problem at hand, when using the `is_component_build` flag, the result is a large number of `.ninja` artifacts, among with many other files under `/gen`, that contain **hard-coded paths** pointing to the build output directory.

Consequently, if one decides to rename the output directory post-build, it disrupts the build integrity if one decides to re-compile incrementally on top of it.

#### Conclusions

Without much of knowledge, an approach I thought of to redistribute the build (say move it to another location) implies running a "*string-find-and-replace*" script that needs to have at least knowledge of what the previous build output path was.

#### Question

Have the ninja build system developers thought of a more formal way of renaming the component build output directories, without having to regenerate the GN meta-build args, to maintain the ability of running incremental builds on a redistributed (moved from path) build output?

If not, what is the correct workflow to re-enable incremental builds on a moved build output directory?

Comment: Perhaps a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334632/are-incremental-builds-possible-with-copied-files-not-built-on-the-machine